# Unable to login to ubuntu after update to 17.04. ctrl+alt+F<anything> doesn't work. Nothing shows up

Tags: upgrade, login, 17.04

Why does ubuntu end up with update issues ? Login screens are the bare minimum to be tested before one makes a release. Is this a known issue? is there a fix other than re-installing ?

Comment: How did you upgrade it?

Comment: Using command line upgrade tool

Comment: Please give the complete command(s)

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade